# How to group and arrange observations if a dataset? Group by is somehow failing

Tags: r, group-by

I need to group observations in a dataset by `route ID` and then arrange them by `year` and `quarter`. I saw that the code that is supposed to work is the following

```
df %>%
  group_by(Route_ID) %>% 
  arrange(year, quarter)
```

but this just puts the observation in ascending order based on `year` and then `quarter`, without grouping them.

However, if I run the `group_by` code only, they are then grouped by `route_ID`, which gets canceled once I add the second part of the code. I  have also tried to put `group_by` after `arrange`, but nothing changed.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: From `?arrange()`: Unlike other dplyr verbs, arrange() largely ignores grouping; you need to explicitly mention grouping variables (or use .by_group = TRUE) in order to group by them, and functions of variables are evaluated once per data frame, not once per group.

Comment: *shrug* I've always assumed it was more "explicitly mention that you'd like to arrange by grouping variables" i.e. `.by_group=TRUE`.

Comment: Solved thanks  a lot!